# Can't install libpng12 due to usrmerge. Can't run PacketTracer without it

Tags: 18.04, 18.10, libpng

I need `libpng12` because of PacketTracer.  Is there a workaround without installing it? Is it safe to remove `usrmerge`?

```
dpkg: regarding libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb containing libpng12-0:amd64:
 usrmerge conflicts with libpng12-0 (<< 1.2.54-4~)
  libpng12-0:amd64 (version 1.2.50-2+deb8u3) is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing libpng12-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

Edit: Just wanna plug [this idea I posted on Cisco's user voice about having a Snap version of Packet Tracer](https://netspace.uservoice.com/forums/168832-instructor-feedback-forum/suggestions/36773896-snap-version-of-packet-tracer) so that installing it in the future won't be such a hassle anymore for newer users (hopefully) who aren't experienced in troubleshooting on Linux.

Comment: It's not because my question involves `usrmerge` being a conflict to `libpng12`
@N0rbert

Comment: OK, I see. Do you really need `usrmerge`?

Comment: @N0rbert I thought installing `usrmerge` is a one-way street?

Comment: The version of `libpng12-0` you're trying to install there has been shipped by Debian but never by Ubuntu. See https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian - the same principle applies to a FrankenUbuntu, which is what you seem to have there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sishe1968 for letting me know that there's a newer version of `libpng12`, but I just wanna add that neither Ubuntu nor Debian aren't providing the current `libpng12` .deb packages from their repos that solves the bug where it won't work with merged `/lib` & `/usr/lib`.  Ubuntu currently has [1.2.54-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libpng12-0), while Debian has [1.2.50-2](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpng12-dev).

You have to go to [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng12/) to download the source file from there

It is version 1.2.59 at the time of writing.

## Steps on installation

1. Extract the source file and go to the `libpng-1.2.59/` directory, where the extracted files are located (FYI that version number could be different in the future).
2. Open a terminal to that directory and type:

   `$ ./configure`

   `$ make check`

   `$ sudo make install`

   `$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng12.{a,so{,.0,0.59.0}} /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.`

Took me a while to realize that I have to symlink, so make sure to not forget that.

Comment: Still the correct answer in 2022 sadly.

Answer (score 0):

`usrmerge` conflicts with that version of `libpng12` because it ships symlinks with the same names in `/lib` and `/usr/lib`, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766809, and on a usrmerged system these are the same file. Uninstalling `usrmerge` doesn't change that. But that bug was fixed in Debian in version 1.2.54-4, so you could try installing a newer version of `libpng12`.

Comment: I got 1.2.54-1 from Ubuntu Xenial repo.  Still conflicts with `usrmerge`.  Just realized that the mailing list specified 1.2.54-4.

Comment: Can't find a deb for it. The one in Debian is 50-2

Comment: Source and binary debian packages here: https://snapshot.debian.org/package/libpng/1.2.54-6/ - the package was removed before it ended up in an official release, but is still available on snapshot.debian.org.